# In Oracle SQL Developer, can I export all table column details as CSV files without clicking on each table and then exporting?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel

I want to export all of information from the "Columns" tab for each table in an Oracle database. I know I can do this manually (click on each table, go to the Columns tab, right click, click "Export", and create a CSV file - included in case there is a better way to do this!), but is there any way to do this without having to go to each table individually? Thank you!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I want to select tables under a specific owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'd just go to **Tools** menu and choose **Database export**. Follow the wizard, for example

- choose connection
- don't export DDL
- export data
- format *insert* statements
- single file
- set target file location and name

On the next screen choose objects to export (you'd probably want to exclude all but tables).

The rest is <Next ... Next> and - that's all. File contents is displayed in SQL Developer, and you'll find it in target folder as well.

---

Step-by-step demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I do that, I get a SQL file that says "--File Created - Friday-September-22-2023" but there's no other information.

Comment: Well, did you select anything to be exported? Are there any objects in schema whose *connection* you chose? Because, it works just fine in my schema.

Comment: I added screenshots that show how I did that (and got result).

Comment: The log panel will show what file was generated, and where it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the screenshots! They're really helpful. I did all of that and still ended up with a SQL file that says "--File Created - Monday-September-25-2023" with no other information. I'm guessing it has to do with how we're using Oracle or something. I'll mark your answer as correct since I'm sure the issue is on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working for me. I was able to export the table owner, table name, column name, and column comments.

SELECT *
FROM all_col_comments
WHERE owner = 'owner_name';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).